# What happened to the StyleRules property in ExCSS?

Tags: c#, excss

I have using:

```
var parser = new Parser();
var sheet = parser.Parse(css);
var query = from rule in sheet.StyleRules select rule;
```

I've upgraded to the latest version (v3.0.0) and changed the above to:

```
var parser = new StylesheetParser();
var sheet = parser.Parse(css);
var query = from rule in sheet.StyleRules select rule;
```

But the `StyleRules` property doesn't exist anymore. What's the new property called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `readme.md` file on the [ExCSS GitHub repository](https://github.com/TylerBrinks/ExCSS), it's now called `Rules`.  Below is the code sample from that page (with a missing semicolon added by me):

> ```
> var parser = new StylesheetParser();
> var stylesheet = parser.Parse(".someClass{color: red; background-image: url('/images/logo.png')");     
>
> var rule = stylesheet.Rules.First();
> var selector = rule.SelectorText; // Yields .someClass
>     var color = rule.Style.Color;
> var image = rule.Style.BackgroundImage; // url('/images/logo.png')
> ```